# Approach to writing ExecutorService for updating AtomicBoolean value

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, executorservice

I'm asking this question specific to this use case, as to what is the best as in most cost-efficient and elegant way to achieve the following:

```
public class MyClass {

  private final AtomicBoolean _myValue = new AtomicBoolean(false);

  public MyClass(MyApi someApi, Executor executor) {
    _someApi = someApi;
    _executor = executor;
  }  

  public startSession() {
    updateValue();
  }

  public sessionEnded() {
   //Do nothing
  }

  public boolean getMyValue() {
      return _myValue.get();
  }

  //the magic should happen here
  private void updateValue() {
    _executor.execute(() => {
        _myValue.set(processValue(_someApi.getValue()));
    });
  }

  //some processing. not that relevant.
  private boolean processValue(Values[] values) {
    try {
      for (...) {... return true;}
    } catch (..) { }
    return false;
  }

}
```

The scenario:
- on each user login `startedSession` is called, meaning it could be 10 users, or 100 users, calling `startedSession` at the same time. The key here is they're all calling set on _myValue. Meanwhile anyone else can be calling `get`.

- and then for the specific handling:

*Options I see:*

**1)**
Implementation-wise let the API consumer have control over the executor size, by passing it through constructor, as done in the example.

**2)** 
Create Executor from within class. 
Example:

```
   MyClass() {
      _executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
   }
```

Calling update to `_myValue`, isn't expected to happen a lot at once, or with frequent changes for `_myValue`, but still I want to follow good practices.

*Options I see:*

**1)** If update is called and running - cancel all current incoming task(update). Once it's finished - accept first incoming and again cancel next ones until current is done, etc. ...

**2)** Queue them and not cancel if one is in progress.

Any suggestions on which approach is better? 
Is it so expensive to queue them, or am I digging too much?

And one last question: how can I make sure my Executor gets shut down and garbage collected without shutting it down while there can still be incoming updating requests?

Open for any suggestions and tips and more options.

Comment: You haven't said what you wanted to achieve in the first place. You have options, but options to do what? Besides, you said "the key here is they're all calling set on _myValue", but you're never calling set anywhere.

Comment: I am: from within updateValue:   
_myValue = processValue(_someApi.getValue());

What I'm thrying to achieve is to handle set and get of _myValue in a concurrent way, so that the most updated value is sure to be sent to each user.

Comment: That doesn't call any set() method. Just read your code. Where do you see `set(...)`?

Comment: Edited the code - it's calling set on the AtmocBoolean.

Comment: You still haven't said what you want to achieve. It's hard to advise a solution without knowing the problem to solve.

Comment: What do you mean by _ the most updated value is sure to be sent to each user_? For example, say users A and B log in "at the same time." Say user A is first to get a value, which is True, then user B gets a value which is False. The most recent value is False, yet A doesn't know about that; it's still using the value it first received, which is True. As JB stated, the problem remains unclear.

Comment: That logic is handled elsewhere. More specifically in the ui - as in
User A logs in - update value.
User B logs in - update value. 
...
User N logs in - update value. 

A, B and everybody who has an older value will get the updated one by navigating to the view that displays it, or in other words by calling get on that value. After a user has loged in(calling update) he might or might not call get afterwards. If he's navigating through another part of the ui - he will not call it. 

My question is related to the updating itself as an operation if multiple users do it at the same time